# Sharing PID with brothers in process tree

Tags: c, process, fork, posix, pid

Well, i have to send signals to process siblings, but i don't know how. I tried to save them in pidx and pidy, but i think that is wrong because i get strange values, like negative numbers. I make a simple example of my problem, thinking that if the third child can have the pid's of his siblings, i can solve it. I'm using Ubuntu to compile (POSIX) and C .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
main(void)
{
pid_t pid;
int x, pidx, pidy;

for(x=1;x<=3;x++)
    {

    pid=fork(); 
    if(pid)
    {
        printf("I'm the process %d\n",getpid());
        sleep(2);
   }

    else{
       //X process
       if (x==0){

           printf("I'm the child %d, my parent is %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
           pidx=getpid();
           sleep(2);
           exit(0);
      }

     //Y process

      if (x==1)
      {
          printf("I'm the child %d, my parent is %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
          pidy=getpid();
          sleep(2);
          exit(0);

    }

      //Z process

      if (x==2)
      {
          printf("I'm the child %d, my parent is %d, and my siblings are \n",getpid(),getppid(), pidx, pidy);
          sleep(2);
          exit(0);

      }


   }
return 0;
}
```

My original code, sorry if it's too long. Bisabuelo means grandgrandson (i'm not sure about that word in English), abuelo means grandson. I need to send signals from Z to the other process if i ask for it in the terminal, but, if i don't know how to comunicate with it siblings, i can't continue.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
void a(){
  printf("Hi, I'm A with PID %d", getpid());
  execlp("pstree","pstree","-la", NULL);

}
void b(){
    printf("Hi, I'm B with PID %d", getpid());
    execlp("pstree","pstree","-la", NULL);

}
void x(){
      printf("Hi, I'm X with PID %d", getpid());
    execlp("ls","ls","-la", NULL);

}
void y(){
    printf("Hi, I'm Y with PID %d", getpid());
    execlp("ls","ls","-la", NULL);

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
 int i, e;
 int bisabuelo, abuelo;
pid_t pid1, pid2, pid3, pidx, pidy;
bisabuelo=getpid();
    if ((pid1=fork())==0 ){
        abuelo=getpid();
        if ((pid2=fork())==0){
            for (i=0;i<3;i++)

            {
                    if ((pid3=fork())>0){
                    if (i==0){
                    printf("I'm a grandson (%d) son of %d, grandson of %d\n",getpid(), getppid(), bisabuelo);
                    signal(SIGUSR1,b);
                    sleep(0);
                    }

                }

                else{
                    sleep(0);
                    switch (i){
                      case 0:{
                        pidx=getpid();
                        printf("I'm the grandgrandson? X (%d) son of %d, grandson of %d, grandgrandson? of %d\n",getpid(), getppid(), abuelo, bisabuelo);
                        signal(SIGUSR1,x);
                        sleep(7);
                        printf("I'm X(%d) and die \n", getpid());
                        exit(0);
                     break; 
                      }
                      case 1:{
                        pidy=getpid();
                        printf("I'm the grandgrandson? Y (%d) son of %d, grandson of %d, grandgrandson? of %d\n",getpid(), getppid(), abuelo, bisabuelo);
                        sleep(5);
                        signal(SIGUSR1,y);
                        printf("Soy Y(%d) y muero \n", getpid());
                        exit(0);


                     break; 
                      }
                      case 2:{
                        printf("I'm the grandgrandson? Z (%d) son of %d, grandson of %d, grandgrandson? of %d\n",getpid(), getppid(), abuelo, bisabuelo);
                        printf("My sibling X is %d and my sibling Z is %d", pidx, pidy);

                        switch (argv[1][0]);
                    {
                        case 'A':
                            //kill(abuelo, SIGUSR1);
                            printf("Me han pasado A");
                            break;
                        case 'B':
                            //kill(getppid, SIGUSR1);
                            printf("Me han pasado B");

                            break;

                        default:
                            printf("No ha introducido ningún argumento");
                            break;
                    }


                        sleep(3);
                        printf("I'm Z (%d) and I die \n", getpid());
                        exit(0);
                     break; 
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
                    wait(&e);
                    wait(&e);
                    wait(&e);
                    sleep(1);
                    printf("I'm B(%d)and I die \n", getpid());


        }
        else{
            printf("I'm A (%d, son of %d)\n", getpid(), getppid());
            signal(SIGUSR1,a);
            wait(&e);
            sleep(1);
            printf("I'm A(%d) and i die \n", getpid());

        }
    }

        else{
            printf("I'm arb (%d)\n", getpid());
            wait(&e);
            printf("I'm arb(%d)and I die\n", getpid());
        }
        sleep(1);

    exit (0);
}
```

Comment: "i think that is wrong": Why?  What behavior did you see, and how did it differ from what you expected?

Comment: Also sexist.  'siblings' would have been more politically correct:)

Comment: I think is wrong because i get strange values, like negative numbers. And, sorry about being sexist... but in my country process is masculine, and i call it brothers :/, i'll try to edit.

Comment: Can you show your actual code? The code above won't compile because the {}'s are unbalanced. (And if I fix that, it works fine.) Also, don't call `exit` in the children, use `_exit`.

Comment: Yes, i can show my code, but is a little mess :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sending signals to multiple processes, you can use "process groups". Basically, sending a signal to `pid= -x` will make the system deliver the signal to every process in process group x. You have to make sure all your "brother" processes (and no other) are in the same process group.
Read more: `man 2 kill`, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group

Comment: Careful, getpid and getppid will return -1 on an error.  Don't send sigkill to process group -1.